# discord.py rewrite - dragging message author to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, python-3.7, discord.py

The title clearly says it, 
How do I go about dragging the message author into the voice channel the bot is currently in?

Say my bot is in a voice channel alone. A command is called to play sound to the author only.

But the author isn't in a voice channel, so I can't use the `move_to(*)` method, hence the word *drag*.

I scrounged the API reference for connections, but I can't seem to find any.

`Is it even possible to drag users into a voice channel?`

Comment: No, I don't believe there's any way for you to force someone else to connect to voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you cannot forcibly connect a client to a voice channel - this would directly violate user privacy. Your idea is akin to 'dragging people into phone calls' unexpectedly.

Comment: Makes sense to me